# unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'int' in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I am qt5 to design an app and here is the sequences of function I am using.

```
self.u = 0
self.u = self.listWidget_3.itemClicked.connect(self.ClickRW1)

self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.push4)
```

Following is the ClickRW1 function

```
def ClickRW1(self, item):
    self.y = item.text()
    if self.y is "June":
        return 0
    elif self.y is "July":
        return 1
    elif self.y is "August":
        return 2
    else:
        return 3
```

When the pushButton_2 is clicked, this function gets called

```
def push4(self):
    plot_rain(self.z, self.u)
```

The plot rain functions -

```
def plot_rain(year, mont):
    if year>2013:
        year = year-1
    n = year-2000
    xc = np.zeros(4)
    for i in range(0,4):
        xc[i] = i
    plt.plot(xc, predicted[((n*16)+(mont*4)):((n*16) + 4 + (mont*4))])
    plt.show()
```

When I click the pushButton_2. Following is the error-

```
plt.plot(xc, predicted[((n*16)+(mont*4)):((n*16) + 4 + (mont*4))])

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

Comment: In future, please include the **full traceback** of the error, not just the last two lines. That'd make it much easier for people to help you, as that shows how Python got to the error, via what path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self.u` is `None`; you set it to `None` here:

```
self.u = self.listWidget_3.itemClicked.connect(self.ClickRW1)
```

The `connect()` call returned `None`.

You then pass `self.u` to `plot_rain()` here:

```
def push4(self):
    plot_rain(self.z, self.u)
```

which uses that value as `mont`, so `mont*4` fails.

The solution is to not assign the `.connect()` result to anything, it doesn't need assigning:

```
self.u = 0
self.listWidget_3.itemClicked.connect(self.ClickRW1)
```